# OCR text recognition

Tags: python-3.x, ocr, opencv3.0, python-tesseract

I am facing a problem in detecting text on a Metal Rod using pytesseract OCR. For other texts it is working fine. I have done some preprocessing, but still it is not detecting. Your help will be much appreciated.

[image: Image of metal rod]

After some preprocessing I got the following output

[image: Image After preprocessing]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2, sys
import pytesseract
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
if __name__ == '__main__':
  image_path = str(sys.argv[1])
  config = ('-l eng --oem 1 --psm 9')
  image = cv2.imread(image_path,1)# cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  ## Preprocessing
  img = gray.copy()
  img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)
  img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
  ret,thresh4 = cv2.threshold(gray,180,255,cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)
  text = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh4, config=config)
  print("TEXT :", text)
  plt.imshow(thresh4, cmap ="gray")
  plt.show()
```

---

Comment: It’s unclear what you are asking here. Can you add the relevant code and what you expect the output to be?

Comment: Basically i have shared 2 images and in that from 1st image i need to extract the text.

Comment: can you add the relevant code for your problem to your question? This will help others have a better shot at answering it.

Comment: Yeah i have just edited it.